# Jupyter conda exception GET /api/kernelspecs two default envs

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda, jupyter-lab

I have installed conda (python 3.5, channel= conda-forge) and several packages with conda and jupyter labextension...

In

```
conda info --envs
```

there is only root and I did not create any additional environment)

[image]

The result is that there are some strange things

1. *An error occurred while retrieving installed packages.*

   ```
   EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: /opt/conda/envs/conda
   ```

and there are two default environments in jupyter conda

2. I get the error while starting jupyter (notebook or lab):

   ```
   [E 16:33:06.973 LabApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/kernelspecs?1525530786969 (172.17.0.1)

   [E 16:35:44.455 LabApp] 500 GET /api/kernelspecs (172.17.0.1) 3.71ms
   ```

   One result is that there are no kernels even they appear at

   ```
   jupyter kernelspec list
   ```

---

One way is to use pip 9.x and

```
pip install --upgrade jupyter-client
```

but I would like to keep it within conda.

Comment: regarding II: in my case I installed toree 0.2.0 (glaxosmithkline) which installed/downgraded jupyter_client to 4.4. 
One solution is to: echo "jupyter_client 5.*" >> $CONDA_DIR/conda-meta/pinned

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to update using pip, and want to update using conda

`conda update jupyter_client jupyter_core`

Comment: conda update does not changes the outcome of the two defaults in jupyter nor the get 500 error

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error. Can you share the steps you used to install ``conda`` extension to jupyter lab. Also could share your environment (list of packages installed with versions)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What solved it for me (for WSL Ubuntu) was:

```
sudo apt install jupyter-core
```

There are some Linux requirements that are not fulfilled by pip alone, I think.